# Did the world know about Wakandan Vibranium before the end of Black Panther?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, black-panther

In *Captain America: Civil War*, there is a scene in Vienna, where king T'Chaka says the following to a large gathering of officials:

> When stolen **Wakandan vibranium** was used to make a terrible weapon, we, in Wakanda, were force to question our legacy. Those men and women killed in Nigeria, were part of a good will mission from a country too long in the shadows.

Now, in *Black Panther* post credits scene, we see that the UN is still unaware of the vibranium and its powers, and that Wakanda possesses it.

Then how can T'Chaka make such a statement at the time of *Civil War*?

Comment: I've forgotten, what was the 'terrible weapon' and which men and women were killed in Nigeria?

Answer (score 24):

### Yes, but not many.

It's possible that Bruce, Tony Stark, and possibly Howard Stark already know about the Wakandan vibranium. Besides them, there are more people who tried to intrude and steal vibranium from Wakanda. One of them is [Ulysses Klaue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaw_(Marvel_Comics)), a guy Ultron gets Vibranium from.

Here are some references.

[Captain America: The First Avenger](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_America:_The_First_Avenger)

> Howard Stark: Vibranium. It's stronger than steel and a third of the weight. It's completely vibration absorbent.
>
> Steve Rogers: How come it's not a standard issue?
>
> Howard Stark: That's **the rarest metal on earth**. What you're holding there? **That's all we've got.**

[Avengers: Age of Ultron](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron)

> Tony Stark: If this guy got out of Wakanda with some of their **trade goods**...
>
> Steve Rogers: I thought your father said **he got the last of it**?
>
> Bruce Banner: I don't follow. What **comes out of Wakanda**? [looking at Steve's shield]
>
> Tony Stark: The strongest metal on earth.

--

> Ultron: ...Upon this rock I will build my church. Vibranium.
>
> Ulysses Klaue: You know, it came at great personal cost. **It's worth billions**.

Now coming to your second question,

> Then how can T'Chaka make such a statement at the time of Civil War?

Well, there were too many casualties in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, which were caused by the weapons made by Ultron using Vibranium. It may not be known to the world, but it was to some people.

Comment: Good answer. One more thing. Then why does the UN doubt _what could Wakanda possibly give us?_ at the end of Black Panther ?

Comment: @Dane If I'm to provide an answer to that.. I believe it was mentioned earlier in the film that Wakanda had given up all of their vibranium when the UN became knowledgeable about them having it. Of course, this wasn't completely true, but perhaps the UN believing so is why they thought Wakanda had nothing to offer [anymore].. ...I could be wrong though?

Comment: I read somewhere that they gave some vibranium pretending that this is all they got in order to prevent attack from foreign nations.

Comment: @AJ Right, that's what I'm referring to. I think the discussion happened when the CIA agent first visited Wakanda, after being injured. He was in the medical bay with the younger girl who's really good with tech, and he noticed the vast caves of vibranium. That's when it was said about Wakanda supposedly giving up all their vibranium.

Answer (score 20):

The world knows about Vibranium, and that Wakanda *had* some of it. When Klaue stole vibranium in the past, they reported to the UN that it was all the vibranium they had in the country. This was likely to prevent others from attempting to steal more.

> Everett K. Ross: My intel reports that the chunk of vibranium you took was all that Wakanda had.
>
> Ulysses Klaue: [laughs, then gets serious] I took that chunk of vibranium out of a MOUNTAIN of the stuff!

T'Chaka's statement is in apology for the vibranium Klaue stole being used to create Ulton, as it is known globally the vibranium used was stolen from Wakanda. But when he was making this statement the world didn't know Wakanda also had more, and it certainly didn't know about their technology.

---

I'm looking for the quote where T'Challa or T'Chaka explicitly says that's the lie they told, but the above will do for now.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that Howard Stark found a small (emphasis on small) deposit of vibranium OUTSIDE of Wakanda. It was just enough to make a small item, like Cap's shield. The asteroid that fell might have had small pieces fall around it when it went through the atmosphere. Thus it stands to chance that one fell outside Wakandan borders just slightly enough for an expedition to discover it.